# How to restart nfsd service on macOS

Tags: macos

The `sudo nfsd restart` command doesn't seem to effect anything. So I tried to stop and then start the service.

When I run

```
$ sudo nfsd stop
```

or

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist
```

it returns:

```
Stopping the nfsd service (use 'disable' to make permanent)
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nfsd.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
```

How to stop the nfsd service without touching the [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) as I found a [few](http://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away) [information](https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/) on the net that we should not stop it.

I'm currently using macOS 10.12.4

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me on macOS **Big Sur:**

`sudo nfsd update`

Note that`sudo nfsd reset` command *does* restart nfsd in a normal system, as evidenced by the pid of `/sbin/nfsd` changing.

But if `update` and `restart` don't work, you should probably check the system log (console app) for errors in your configuration. You could try to `kill -9`  the daemon and restart it manually of launchd doesn't automatically reload it, and check that the PID changes.

The man page documents the following command line options (among many other things not listed here):

`man nfsd`

```
     nfsd is normally launched by launchd(8); however, the nfsd command may also be 
     used to manipulate the service using the following commands:

     enable   Enables the nfsd service.

     disable  Disables the nfsd service.

     start    Starts the nfsd service.  Note: if the service is disabled it will 
              not be restarted on reboot.  Use the enable command 
              to make the change permanent.

     stop     Stops the nfsd service.  Note: if the service is enabled it will be 
              restarted on reboot.  Use the disable command      
              to make the change permanent.

     restart  Restarts the nfsd service (by stopping the service - it will restart automatically if the /etc/exports file exists).

     update   Sends a SIGHUP to the running nfsd daemon 
              to cause it to update its configuration.

     status   Displays whether the nfsd service 
              is enabled and whether the nfsd daemon is currently running.

     checkexports
              Checks the exports file and reports any errors 
              (to stderr).  Note that this can be useful to verify 
              the validity of an alternate exports file 
              (using the -F option below) prior to putting the 
              changes in place and updating nfsd.
```